# lambda in python and beautiful soup is not retrieving text

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape 1520-00-087-7637 from this html

```
     <tr>
<td class="text-center" style="width: 10%">
    <img class="img-thumbnail" src="/Files/image/placeholder100.png" style="width: 100px">
</td>

<td class="text-center" nowrap="" style="vertical-align: middle; width: 10%"><a href="/NSN/1520-00-087-7637">1520-00-087-7637</a></td>
<td class="text-center" nowrap="" style="vertical-align: middle; width: 10%"><a href="/PartNumber/UH1H">UH1H</a></td>

<td class="text-center" nowrap="" style="vertical-align: middle; width: 10%"><a href="/CAGE/97499">97499</a></td>
<td class="text-center" style="vertical-align: middle; width: 10%"><a href="/CAGE/97499"><img class="img-thumbnail" src="/Files/cage/90/97499.jpg" title="CAGE 97499" alt="CAGE 97499"></a></td>
<td nowrap="" style="vertical-align: middle">

    <h4>&emsp;&emsp;BOSS, MAN</h4>


    <p>
        <em>&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;Alternate References: <a href="/NSN/1520-00-087-7637">1520-00-087-7637</a>, <a href="/NSN/1520-00-087-7637">000877637</a></em>
    </p>
</td>
```

so I try to use this to get 1520-00-087-7637 but all i get from the output is none.

```
page_soup1 = soup(page_html1, "html.parser")

tablecontainer = page_soup1.find_all("tr")

for container in tablecontainer:

    Z = container1.find('a', {'href': lambda x : x.startswith('/NSN/')})

    print(Z)
```

what am I doing wrong and how can I fix this

I tried print(Z.get_text()) and Z.text none of them seems to be working. how can i get the text value?

Comment: you also have a typo, you reference `container` for variable assignment but then try to find the links in `container1`

Comment: @aws_apprentice you're right. by how do I get the text. I tried  print(Z.get_text()) and Z.text none of them seems to be working

Comment: Is it necessary to stick to lamda? Bacause, I've another solution to give you to serve the same purpose if you like.

Comment: @Shahin please post it. It is not a must

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here it is. Let me know if you have any issues with it. It seems that I need to walk you through.

```
from lxml.html import fromstring
tree = fromstring(html)
for item in tree.cssselect(".text-center+td h4"):
    print(item.text_content())
```

Result:

```
BOSS, MAN
```

And to get the data from a container:

```
html='''
<tr>
    <td class="text-center" style="width: 10%">
        <img class="img-thumbnail" src="/Files/image/placeholder100.png" style="width: 100px">
    </td>
    <td class="text-center" nowrap="" style="vertical-align: middle; width: 10%"><a href="/NSN/1520-00-087-7637">1520-00-087-7637</a></td>
    <td class="text-center" nowrap="" style="vertical-align: middle; width: 10%"><a href="/PartNumber/UH1H">UH1H</a></td>

    <td class="text-center" nowrap="" style="vertical-align: middle; width: 10%"><a href="/CAGE/97499">97499</a></td>
    <td class="text-center" style="vertical-align: middle; width: 10%"><a href="/CAGE/97499"><img class="img-thumbnail" src="/Files/cage/90/97499.jpg" title="CAGE 97499" alt="CAGE 97499"></a></td>
    <td nowrap="" style="vertical-align: middle">
        <h4>&emsp;&emsp;BOSS, MAN</h4>
        <p>
            <em>&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;Alternate References: <a href="/NSN/1520-00-087-7637">1520-00-087-7637</a>, <a href="/NSN/1520-00-087-7637">000877637</a></em>
        </p>
    </td>
</tr>
'''

from lxml.html import fromstring
tree = fromstring(html)
for item in tree.cssselect("tr"):
    number = item.cssselect(".text-center a[href^='/NSN/']")[0].text
    name = item.cssselect(".text-center+td h4")[0].text_content()
    print(number, name)
```

Result:

```
1520-00-087-7637   BOSS, MAN
```

Comment: I have not been able to integrate this solution with "html.parser". so I would like to use this to obtain all my values then. How can I use lxml method to obtain "Boss Man"

Comment: Just paste the full script along with html elements (everything) in your idle and run it. I thought you know how to run.

Comment: i was the able to the result I just want to see how to implement it to other values in the html. I can implement it to also get part number but I need to get "Boss Man"

Comment: See the edit. Btw, you don't have any specific question. Do you?

Comment: Again see the edit to get two of them in a single run from a container. Thanks.